# SSRS identify odd and even rows in grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a shared stored procedure which as an example provides me with a list of Items and quantities.
This list can have the same Item occurring several times.

I am looking to write an SSRS report, grouping at Item level, which I have completed.

The detail of the report is now across 2 columns and currently I have 2 separate tables, one for odd rows (Col 1, 3, 5 etc) and the other for even rows (Col 2, 4, 6 etc).

How can I identify the specific row number of each grouping to allow me add each line to the respective table.

Example
Provided list from Stored Procedure

A, 1

A, 2

A, 1

B, 2

C, 2

C, 2

C, 1

I want my report to look as follows (Ignore the ... as this was for spacing only):

Column-A....Column-B

A, 4..............B, 2

C, 5

I am relatively new to SSRS so an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: add a filter to the tablix grouping which filters by (rownumber mod 2) = 0 and (rownumber mod 2) = 1

Comment: Whereas previously each table had the same data, after adding the filters to each table under the Item grouping, I am now not seeing any data.

Comment: I added the expression you suggested as a column inside the group and it reports the number of rows making up that grouped element. I'm specifically after the unique row number of the grouped item in the report. Using the example above I would like to see Row 1=A, Row 2=B, Row 3=C.

Comment: so you want to add a partent group which groups by letter and a sum row which displays the letter and the sum(number) and hide the detail rows... something like that? also the rownumber should be handled in your stored procedure since the rownumber(nothing) function doesnt work for filters

Comment: That's pretty much it but unfortunately it a stored procedure, which is shared across a number of different reports so I'm not in a position to change it. Is there anyway I can add a sequence number to each row in the report, outside the group, which I can then filter on using SeqNo Mod 2?

Comment: Is there any other way I can split a grouped item across 2 columns?

Comment: i would have to see your query to answer that

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by using the record key from the stored procedure and creating a new dataset in my report. I extracted only the details I required and applied a GROUP BY and included a row number within my SQL. Using the report filter (SeqNum Mod 2) in my SSRS, I managed to isolate each column into the respective table. Thanks for you assistance Bacon.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved and in a roundabout way I now have the correct results.